# Replicate alternating vector values

Tags: r, vector

I can't figure out how to produce a vector from `3` to `50` where the even numbers are replicated twice and the uneven numbers once, such that the vector would be

```
3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, ..., 50, 50
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rep()` will do the trick.

```
x <- 3:50
rep(x, (x %% 2 == 0) + 1L)
#  [1]  3  4  4  5  6  6  7  8  8  9 10 10 11 12 12 13 14 14 15 16 16 17
# [23] 18 18 19 20 20 21 22 22 23 24 24 25 26 26 27 28 28 29 30 30 31 32
# [45] 32 33 34 34 35 36 36 37 38 38 39 40 40 41 42 42 43 44 44 45 46 46
# [67] 47 48 48 49 50 50
```

`x %% 2 == 0` gives a logical vector indicating which elements of `x` are even.  Since the integer values of `TRUE` and `FALSE` are `1` and `0` respectively, adding 1 to `x %% 2 == 0` gives us the vector we need for our `times` argument in `rep()`.

If we're playing golf, we can shorten it to `rep(x, (!x %% 2) + 1L)`.

Note that this method will also be useful if our original vector is *not* sequential, and we still want the even values replicated.

```
v <- c(1, 2, 4, 3, 6)
rep(v, (!v %% 2) + 1L)
# [1] 1 2 2 4 4 3 6 6
```

Comment: and a little more hard-coded: `rep(3:50, rep(1:2, 24))`

Answer (score 8):

we can merge a vector of all the values and a vector of the even numbers together:

```
sort(c(3:50, 2:25*2))
```

Answer (score 5):

Using recycling, a bit manual way:

```
x <- 3:50
sort(c(x, x[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
```